# Limit of radical function $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \left(-h - \sqrt{h^2+1}\right)^{T/h}$

Tags: limits

Given $h>0$ and $T$ is a constant, how to compute following limit?

$\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \left(-h - \sqrt{h^2+1}\right)^{T/h}$

My attempt:

$\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \left(-h - \sqrt{h^2+1}\right)^{T/h} = \lim\limits_{h\to 0} (-h)^{T/h} \ \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \left( 1 + \sqrt{1 + h^{-2}}\right)^{T/h}$

But I do not know hot to proceed =(

Comment: are you sure $h>0$? How about  $T$? Eg, for $h=1$, you have $(-1-\sqrt{2})^T$. Raising a negative number to arbitrary power is not always defined (if you want the result to still be real number...)

Comment: @Chip Yes, both $h$ and $T$ are positive, so as $T/h$. $T$ is a fixed constant, and $h\to0^+$. Also, $\left\lvert\,-h - \sqrt{h^2+1}\,\right\rvert>1$, why would there be a problem with raising it to a positive power?

Comment: well, you can try to compute say, $(-1.234)^{0.23}$...